# Is it possible to pass configuration values as arguments to services?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I'm writing a module that makes calls to a Web service to read and store data. 
Here's my services.yml file:

```
services:
  example.connection:
    class: Drupal\Core\Http\Client
```

I've already a settings form (inheriting from ConfigFormBase) that stores a base URL in configuration, and I'd like to pass that as an argument to the Client class's constructor. I've tried this:

```
class ExampleServiceProvider implements ServiceModifierInterface {

  /**
   * Modifies existing service definitions.
   *
   * @param ContainerBuilder $container
   *   The ContainerBuilder whose service definitions can be altered.
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $base_url = $container->get('config.factory')
        ->get('example_entity.settings')->get('base_url');
    if ($base_url) {
      $arguments = array('base_url' => $base_url);
      $container->getDefinition('example.connection')
        ->setArguments(array($arguments));
    }
  }
}
```

But that gives me HTTP 403 errors for every page on the site. Should it be possible to pass arbitrary arguments like this? Hardcoding a URL into the $base_url variable works fine.

Comment: The recommended way is to pass in the config.factory as dependency to the actual service. In the service then pull the values from here. One reason for this is that config might be altered dynamically.

Comment: Agreed. Also it seems like having a ClientFactory as a service instead would be useful, as you could inject both factories and then create the Client with the config. That would require a core issue.

Comment: @daniel-wehner Thanks! I ended up creating a `connection_factory` service with a ClientFactory class and passing the `config.factory` service in as an argument, similar to the final example on the Symfony documentation page [Using A Factory To Create Services](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/components/dependency_injection/factories.html), which I hadn't discovered up until now.

Answer (score 2):

In your services file add the following service:

```
# The bar configuration for the foo module
config.foo.bar.immutable:
  class: \Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig
  factory: config.factory:get
  arguments: ['bar']
config.foo.bar.mutable:
  class: \Drupal\Core\Config\Config
  factory: config.factory:getEditable
  arguments: ['bar']
```

In your service create method add either `config.foo.bar.immutable` or `config.foo.bar.mutable` service as an argument.